# IE and javascript and binary data

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Can anyone offer any advice please?

I have a very simple serverside node.js function which receives binary data and just echos it back:

```
app.post('/SetBinaryData', function(req, res)
                               {
                                    var echo = new Buffer(0);

                                    req.on('data', function (data)
                                    {
                                        echo = Buffer.concat([echo,data]);
                                    });

                                    req.on('end', function ()
                                    {
                                        res.end(echo);
                                    }); 
                               }
   );
```

I call it from client side on the click of a button as follows:

```
function OnButton3()
{
    var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(8 + 2);

    var dataview = new DataView(buffer);

    dataview.setFloat64(0, 3.4, false);

    dataview.setInt16(8, 7 , false);

    AJAXSendBinaryData(AJAXGetRequestObject(), "[URL HERE]/SetBinaryData", "args=1,2,3", dataview, OnServerBinaryCallCompleted, 9, false);
}
```

My AJAX call (wrapped in my function AJAXSendBinaryData) has the following attributes:

```
ajaxRequestObject.open('POST', szURL, true);
ajaxRequestObject.responseType = "arraybuffer";
ajaxRequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
```

and the onload function contains:

```
ajaxRequestObject.onload = function(oEvent)
{
    var arrayBuffer = ajaxRequestObject.response;

    if(arrayBuffer)
    {
        var dataView = new DataView(arrayBuffer);

        OnCallCompleted(dataView);
    }
}
```

The OnCallCompleted method is:

```
function OnServerBinaryCallCompleted(dataview)
{
    var value1 = dataview.getFloat64(0);
    var value2 = dataview.getInt16(8);
    alert(dataview.byteLength);
    alert(value1.toString() + "\n" + value2.toString());
}
```

This works on Firefox, Opera, Chrome.

I see the first alert of '10' (the number of bytes I sent) and then I see the message 3.4 and 7.

BUT, in Internet Explorer 11 I see not 10 but 15 (regardless of how much data I send)

(Note, may be helpful, if I define the data as:

```
var data = [253.432, 0.432, 128.654, 1.456];
var dataview = new Float64Array(data);
```

and send that, and on the callback just handle it as an array then all is well on all browsers. But I want to mix data types).

Thanks for any thoughts,
Mitch.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Bug in IE. Fix by sending ArrayBuffer object to AJAX request instead of the DataView object. Works on all browsers now.

Mitch.